# C# - How do I pass a model with another model inside from a HTML form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have this form I'm trying to pass to my controller. I have another model inside the main model.

he models and the form are like this. Don't know if the controller will pickup the model like this

```cs
public class Entry{
    public string id { get; set;}
    public string department { get; set; }
    public Supervisor supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Supervisor{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string employeeID { get; set; }
}
```

```
<form action="Home/Upload" method="post" style="border:solid #000 1px; padding:5px">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Entry</legend>

        ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
        Department: <input type="text" name="department" />
        <br /><br />

        Supervisor<br />
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
        Employee Id: <input type="text" name="employeeID"/><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(Entry newEntry){
        Database db = new Database();
        bool result = db.add(newEntry);
        return View("UploadResult", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The names of the input fields are not correct. Just use the @Html.TextBoxFor(...) method to create the fields in the cshtml file. You should read more about model binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the supervisor details you have to name it accordingly as :

```
    Name: <input type="text" name="supervisor.name"/>
    Employee Id: <input type="text" name="supervisor.employeeID"/><br />
```